# NativeScript - Try to start Android emulator (Cannot find connected devices)

Tags: android, nativescript

I use **NativeScript** to develop a mobile application. I try to emulate the app with `tns run android --emulator` but I've the following error after 1 minute or less.

```
λ tns run android --emulator
Searching for devices...
Starting Android emulator with image Pixel_2_API_25
Cannot find connected devices.
Emulator start failed with: Cannot run your app in the native emulator. Increase the timeout of the operation with the --timeout option or try to restart your adb server with 'adb kill-server' command. Alternatively, run the Android Virtual Device manager and increase the allocated RAM for the virtual device.
To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
To list available emulator images, run 'tns device <Platform> --available-devices'.
```

I've a emulator device (*Pixel 2 API 2*) when I type this command: `tns device android --available-devices`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes Emulator can take long to launch. The alternative can be to launch the emulator on which you want to run using Android Studio-> AVD Manager and then tns run android to launch your application on the emulator.